# Unknown label type: 'continuous' in SVM model for stock price prediction

Tags: python, svm, svc

I am trying to write a code for SVM. My purpose is to predict stock price for weekly S&P stock. I used Apple weekly stock prices for `y_train`, and my `x_train` is market prices and two Fama-french factors.

At the end of the code I encounter:

> Unknown label type: 'continuous'.

I have no idea what the problem is. Can you help? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics

data = pd.read_csv('combine_weekly.csv',sep=',')

data= data[['return_app','return_sp','SMB','HML']]

predict='return_app'

x= np.array(data.drop([predict],1))
y= np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = 
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel= 'linear', C= 4)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train).     <<<<< >>>*** here I get the error ***


y_pred = clf.predict(x_test )
acc= metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(acc)
```

Comment: It is enough to change from SVC to SVR, i.e. from a classifier to a regressor model.

Answer (score 0):

Your labels are Continuous numbers (like 1, 2, 3.5, 4.2, 5.6, etc)  which can be handled as a regression problem. Though you are using svm.SVC which is a Classifier(where we get classes as labels like 'fruit', 'vegetable', etc & no real numbers as in your case) & not regressor. You can opt for  LinearRegression, XGBRegressor, etc. for this problem